# MongoDB - Find documents with earliest occurrence of duplicate value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection within MongoDB (4.4 but the version isn't important to me) and one of the document values is an array of URLs. There will be multiple documents with multiple URLs per document (within the array) and some of those URLs will already exist.
I would like to select each document with the earliest occurrence of each URL (the intention being to mark it as the 'origin'.

MongoPlayground link for sample collection - https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZAgCqr517-8

```
  {
    "title": "story1_first",
    "isoDate": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "links": [
      "www.first.com/article1",
      "www.anotherdomain.com"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "story1_mention",
    "isoDate": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "links": [
      "www.first.com/article1",
      "www.somesite.com"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "story2_first",
    "isoDate": "2022-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "links": [
      "www.newstory.com/article2",
      "www.anothercompany.com"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "story2_mention",
    "isoDate": "2022-01-20T00:00:00.000Z",
    "links": [
      "www.newstory.com/article2",
      "www.anothercompany.com"
    ]
  }
]
```

In this example, I would like the query / aggregation to return the two documents with "first" in the title as they are the documents which share a common URL within 'links' and are the documents which have the earliest date. Similar to how a search engine ranks up a site depending on how many other sites link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$unwind` `links` so the documents are in links level
2. `$sort` on `isoDate` to get the first document
3. `$group` by `links` to get count inbetween group and the id of the first document. In your example, title is taken as unique identifier.
4. `$match` with count > 1 to get `title` that share the same link
5. `$group` to dedupe the unique identifier we found in step 3
6. `$lookup` back the original document and do some cosmetics by `$replaceRoot`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$links"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      isoDate: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$links",
      first: {
        $first: "$title"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$first"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "title",
      "as": "rawDocument"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$rawDocument"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$rawDocument"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fCjnLBVFoYB) for your reference.

Comment: Excellent answer with details explanation @ray

Comment: @ray that's awesome, thanks for the answer and the clear explanation too.